# How to return a rejected promise when it takes the function too long to return a response by itself in Node?

Tags: node.js, promise, cancellation

I made a back-end in Node.js.

The back-end contains a function named algorithm.make(). This function has a promise as return type.
Sometimes the application needs three seconds to fully execute the algoritm.make function and sometimes it needs ten minutes.

I would like to always return a response (a resolved or rejected promise) after a specific amount of seconds.

I tried:

```
....

try {
       return await Promise.race([
           this.wait(4000),
           algorithm.make()
       ]);
} catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
}
```

Wait function:

```
static wait(ms) {
    return new Promise((_, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('timeout succeeded ' + ms)), ms);
    });
}
```

With this code the algorithm.make() will just fully execute (and it will not be stopped after 4000ms).

But when I do this, it will return a rejected promise after 2 seconds:

```
try {
       return await Promise.race([
           this.wait(4000),
           this.wait(2000),
       ]);
} catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
}
```

I don't know why it is working with two setTimeouts but not with one setTimeout and one real function.

Comment: A promise is *just* a notification mechanism for when a task is complete. It doesn't actually control the task. Both your code blocks work exactly alike - in both cases two async tasks are launched, one finishes earlier, the other *still completes later* but you are nto notified of that.

Comment: `Promise.race` doesn't stop anything, all it does is to settle the returned promise. If you actually want to stop the algorithm, you need to explicitly tell it to do so - and write the algorithm in a way so that it can be aborted.

Comment: @Bergi is right. _One_ way to do that is to adopt the [AbortController](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_class_abortcontroller). [Examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController). Pass the `signal` property of `new AbortController()` to your `make()` fn, inside `make` you should reject if `signal.aborted===true` & do `wait(4000).then(_ => abortcontroller.abort())` to trigger the abort.

Comment: @RickN I tried to implement the AbortController but the code returns error 400 when executing the next line: const controller = new AbortController();

Comment: You may be running node 14. It was added in version 15. You don't _have to_ use the AbortController. Just keep in mind what the other comments said: `Promise.race` doesn't cancel your running code, just suppresses any resolved/rejected value (except the first one of course!). AbortController helps you do it in a 'standard' way.

Answer (score 1):

I tried another approach and that was working.

In the Node.js function I calculated the date/time when it will took too long to respond.

```
this.returnTime = new Date();
this.returnTime.setSeconds( this.returnTime.getSeconds() + this.timer );
```

And then I added an extra check in a function that is looped several times:

```
if(this.returnTime > new Date()) {
 .....
```

So if the current date/time is newer than the this.returnTime, then it will return something. Otherwise it will keep going